# Self-Promotion or Manipulating SO License?

Tags: discussion, self-promotion, licensing

[I recently had an edit made to a question removing "Self-Promotion"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63295867/revisions). I did some reading and didn't find a clear consensus, but what I understood was if it [the link] provides further details, but isn't a link only answer it's generally accepted (but I did find conflicting information on that topic). I'm still unsure of the SOP on linking to ones own site, but my concern is two fold and perhaps this question should be limited to the following regarding SO's licensing.

Update: **To be clear, I'm more concerned with the licensing aspect then posting "Self-Promotion"** as I haven't had this issue often (links removed by mod's), it just so happened a mod was looking at my post for other reasons (cleaning up comments) and I think decided to make the edit. This got me thinking about the licensing aspect of the situation.

I'm a bit hazy on the details, but I use SO heavily when coding (both as a resource and question/answer forum) and recently signed a confidentiality agreement which had me revisit the licensing thought.  From what I do understand/saw in a comment is that if code is pasted from an external source and linked SO doesn't have the right/capability to change the original authors licensing/rights etc.

So my question is, could "Self-Promotion" really be manipulating SO's licensing capabilities perhaps in your favor?

IE: **If I post to my site my code, then share the answer w/ SO linking to my site, do I not retain the rights to license my code as I see fit?**

If so, how can it be OK to remove my links via an edit/How can SO detect "Self-Promotion" vs "Licensing Manipulation".

PS: If you check out the link in the edit vs the question, I would say this is clearly an example "further reading" but not a link only answer. I find it could be very likely if people found that question/answer useful, the link could provide useful but isn't relative to the question and the answer is self-sufficient.

Comment: You post a link but I don't see in your answer any explanation of the link, any rationale for why you posted it, and since the link name matches your sign-on name, that is a suggestion of self-promotion or worse, spam (but of course,  not proof of either). If you are going to post a link, best to fully explain why the link is there and why you feel that it is absolutely necessary

Comment: Wait, do most of your answers contain links to your site? You do know that one of the goals of this site is for all relevant information to be present in the questions and answers themselves and to use links to external resources only for absolute need.

Comment: All relevant details are always posted in answer, further reading implies extended looking into a topic generally unrelated to the question, but "On Topic" of the questions goals.

Comment: Again, do or did most of your answers contain such links?

Comment: See my previous comment `Most of my posts have a link to further reading`

Comment: When you want to link to your own work (library, website, etc.), make sure that a) you explicitly **disclose** your relationship with the"product". b) it's **relevant** to the post. c) it naturally **fits into the context** of your answer. d) you **don't spam** it into most/all of your answers; even with disclosure, that's usually frowned upon.

Comment: That's fine to link "for further reading" to independent resources. If they're all to your site, that's promotion. Not good.

Comment: How does it benefit anybody to not link an external resource with further reading? This is not a product for sale but simply more information.

Comment: Because this is your own site, you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when linking to it in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under SO policy.

Comment: 11 No Link and 6 had a link of 17 of my last answers, so not as much as I thought. I think I tend to link to futher reading when I answer my own question vs somebody elses.

Comment: @RyanM that is clear instructions that make sense. I will disclose as well as explain (in a short preface) to any URLs.

Comment: Since you insisted to know why downvotes - the question asks two unrelated questions: one - why post is downvoted that is discussed to death on meta and there is no indication that author did any research on why post can be downvoted. And the second very poorly asked "is linking from content under license A impacts license of linked content under License B" which is somewhat obvious and really not on-topic on meta (https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ may be more suitable depending on "License B"). And indeed I voted to close as post is too broad.

Comment: Very rude... Somewhat obvious. I must just be an idiot. Also, I think your confusing cause and effect, it would seem obvious to me I posted the request for clarification on downvotes after receiving them.

Comment: Well, you asked about why there are downvotes. Your reaction to the answer to why is a good reason most people choose to not comment when downvoting. And no, just because you own the license to the content you're *linking* to does not mean you have the same control over your post here that contains the link. The link can be removed from here regardless. The content you own isn't affected by that, it's on another site. Hence the need for a link.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I'm not exactly sure what you mean "confusing cause and effect" - you've made the decision that one question in the post is not enough and added the second one (it was quite clear that it is a recent edit without the clarifying comment due to improper "update:" text). This made question too broad (and asking about downvotes is not very new topic on meta as I mentioned). Usually I would just roll back such edit to keep question focused but I get a feeling that you would not appreciate that, so to save you a trouble of rollback war I voted on the *current state of the post*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer your specific licensing question without touching on the self-promotion policy:

> If I post to my site my code, then share the answer w/ SO linking to my site, do I not retain the rights to license my code as I see fit?

Linking to your site from Stack Overflow does not, in any way, affect the licensing terms of the content that is linked.  The CC BY-SA license only applies to content posted *on* the Stack Exchange network itself, not merely linked from it.  This is one reason it is forbidden for users to edit questions to move code from pastebin-style links into a question: only the author of the code (or someone to whom the author has given a license that allows relicensing) can relicense it, so only they may post it (unless it is already explicitly under a compatible license).

This is also a reason why we require answers to be self-contained (a rule which you have not violated here).  If the answer is in a link, then the code isn't made available under the permissive license that it would be if it were posted directly on the site.

Comment: So just to be clear, what is the licensing effect if somebody posts content they didn't have permission to post on SO?

Comment: The person who posted content without permission may have (depending on many factors, such as fair use and whether the content was copyrightable in the first place) violated the author's copyright, as well as Stack Overflow policy.  The author may have legal remedies against the poster. You (or anyone who notices such copying) should also flag the post for moderator attention to alert moderators to the copying, as copied content must at least be [cited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) under SO policy.

Comment: So basically, as you simply stated (thank you) `The CC BY-SA license only applies to content posted on the Stack Exchange` and once the code is posted, the license applies. If it shouldn't have been posted, it enters the realm of the `legal system` etc etc (case by case at that point).

Comment: Correct. Someone without the rights to license content cannot grant such a license, so their posting it would have no effect on the content's licensing.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Note however, that while moderators will remove plagiarism when the OP doesn't comply with the [referencing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), moderators are not here to arbitrate copyright. Copyright is a legal issue. Given that Stack Exchange is in the US, the proper way to handle a claim that someone posting your content is violating your copyright is to file a [DMCA takedown notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notice_and_take_down#United_States).

Answer (score 13):

### TL;DR the link needed to go.

It started by a comment thread that was flagged for deletion.

Reading the answer above, it appears that your username and the name of the site linked last (out of the blue) is a perfect match. Besides, the name itself (FreeSoftwareServers) makes me think of a commercial thing.

That is considered spam. Since you have some reputation on this site, the answer seems to contain useful information, and you posted that link only once, that doesn't warrant a spam flag, so I simply removed the links while cleaning up the comments.

I should have left a comment of why I removed the link. Lazy me.

Comment: Yes, lazy you could have spared us a meta post and comment thread. But have an upvote for entertainment value ;)

Comment: thanks rene. I thrive on meta votes that's why

Comment: No No, you did leave a comment on why, it just got me thinking about learning more in regards to licensing and self-promotion polices. Which, is why comments on downvotes and edits are super important. I'm fairly thick skinned, but without any rationale many people take it too personally.